# Access GAE datastore with spray

Tags: java, scala, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, spray

I want to use GAE datastore to store my data but instead of the java API we want to use the [JSON API](https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/v1beta2/) and making requests through spray.

But before I can even do any request I need to obtain an access token.

I can't figure out how this is done with either the Java API or any other means. Is there a way to obtain an access token which can then be used for the JSON API (through spray)?

Answer (score 1):

Like many Google services, the Datastore API uses OAuth for authentication.  The easiest way to use it is with one of the Google API client libraries.

Java: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/
Java + Datastore: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/datastore/v1beta2

The documentation for the client does a pretty good job of explaining how OAuth works and how to get started calling APIs by registering your app with the Console.

(I'm not familiar with spray, but I assume you'd be able to use the Java client from Scala.)

Comment: Thank you for the links, but would it be possible to use the java libraries only to obtain and refresh the access tokens, and doing the actual retrieving and storing of the entities through the `Json API`? I couldn't figure out how this would work fromt he documentation

Comment: Typically you would use the library to call the service.  A token has to be included with each request, so it's easier if the library just make the call for you.  There's not much point to extracting the token from the library and assembling the JSON messages manually.  Is there a reason why you'd want to do it that way?